# Good chess puzzle that involves queen running around the board?

Tags: problems, puzzles

Basically title. Ideally not too difficult or too many steps, but if you have any good puzzles where the queen traverses across the board.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may search for 'ladder' tactics, but I am not sure if this is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, "running around" is a bit unspecific, but nevertheless, here are some offhand suggestions.

- "The ladder" Brian suggested you can see in problem chess, but also in the Philidor position in the Q vs R endgame: Kc6 Qa5 - Kb8 Rb7, black to move, e.g. 1...Rb1 2.Qd8+ Ka7 3.Qe7+ Kb8 4.Qf8+ Ka7 5.Qf7+ (a bit precision, please) Kb8 6.Qg8+ Ka7 7.Qa2+ 1-0
- "Merry Go Round" #4 by Jan Dobrusky,
  None Schachmatnoe Obozrenie 1901.
  8/3B4/1K1p4/2pNk3/2bn1b2/3p4/5N2/Q7
- "Eine Schwalbe": A four-mover which gave the name to the German problem chess journal AND to the formal theme "A single white piece does all the work" (so googling "Schwalbeform" will find more). See here: https://www.dieschwalbe.de/ueberuns.htm

Is there something in my post which fulfils your request? Elsewise, be more specific.